# How to use a GWT application in Angular 7 application as a component?

Tags: angular, gwt, angular7, angular-routing, smartgwt

I have an Angular 7 application with which I want to use a Single Page GWT application as a component. The reason for using that GWT app as a component is that I don't want my GWT app to reload again and again whenever I navigate to that app (or page) using Angular routing.

Here's what I tried:

- Firstly, I placed the compiled binaries of that GWT project in the assets folder of my Angular app. Then I put all the content under the  tag of it's index.html in the component.html file of my Angular app. Then added a button and applied router navigation on it's click event so that clicking that button would navigate to my Angular app's component page.
- I embed the GWT app in an iFrame in an Angular component. But I observed that while navigating to that page through routing, it was reloading again and again whenever I navigated back and forth to that page and to another Angular page using routing.
- I also added the path of all the needed javascript files of GWT app in the **scripts** parameter in the angular.json file and modified **allowJs** parameter to true in tsconfig.json.
- I know that when building the Angular project creates main.js file which contains the compiled JS code for all the components including their routing. So, I also thought of converting the main nocache.js file of GWT to the TS file, but it caused a lot of syntax errors, so I ignored this procedure.

Now with my limited knowledge, I can't think of any solutions except those specified above and I got really stuck at this situation and couldn't go ahead with my project.

So, can anyone please help me to find it's solution? I'm also not sure about whether it's possible to do this or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding another answer to address the issue mentioned in the comment of the first answer. The problem is that the `iframe` inside a component still gets reloaded even if the component is kept alive by the [RouteReuseStrategy](https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy). This is probably caused because Angular detaches it from the page DOM and then reattaches it.

One work around solution is to keep the component with the `iframe` always alive inside your main application component and just hide it when you navigate to another page. Then show it again if you navigate to the route where you want to show it. You can do that by using [Router events](https://angular.io/guide/router#router-events).

Here is a sample application component that implements this workaround. The `gwt` component is the component with the iFrame.

The template:

```
<h2><a routerLink="/main">Main</a></h2>
<h2><a routerLink="/gwt">Gwt</a></h2>
<gwt [hidden]="!gwtVisible"></gwt>
<router-outlet [hidden]="gwtVisible"></router-outlet>
```

The code:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  gwtVisible = false;

  constructor(router: Router) {
    router.events.subscribe((routerEvent) => {
      if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.gwtVisible = routerEvent.url === '/gwt';
      }
    });
  }
}
```

As you can see from the code the application component hides the main content when you navigate to the `/gwt` route and shows the `gwt` component else it hides it and shows the other content normally from the `router-outlet`.

In the routes I have defined that it navigates to an empty component just to have something for the route `/gwt`.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'main', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'main', component: MainComponent },
  { path: 'gwt', component: EmptyComponent }
];
```

I have created also a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dzzhke-route-reuse-ayixtq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) with a working sample.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although by using the exact code as yours, the iframe was getting displayed twice in the page.
So, I am able to achieve the desired objective by using "*ngIf" instead of "[hidden]" in <router-outlet> statement in html to "<router-outlet *ngIf="!gwtVisible"></router-outlet>"

Comment: by using the RoutingReuseStrategy, I am not able to read the query parameters in my root component, which I was previously able to do successfully. So, can you suggest what to do in that case?

Comment: For this solution you don't need the `RouteReuseStrategy`. I have removed it in the sample. Use [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute) here is a [sample from the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route-in-action) on how to read parameters. If this does not work you can also change to the [ActivationEnd](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivationEnd) event where I used the `NavigationEnd` event. There you also have the information about parameters in the [snapshot property](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivationEnd#properties).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to keep an angular component (page) alive when you navigate to other routes.

Angular routing by default destroys the component every time you go to another and creates it again when you return to it. This is why it loads every time again.
What you need to do is implement a custom [RouteReuseStrategy](https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy) that will keep your component alive.

Here is a very simple implementation that assumes your component with the GWT application has the route 'gwt'.

```
export class GwtRouteReuseStrategy extends RouteReuseStrategy {
  private cache: {[key: string]: DetachedRouteHandle} = {};

  public shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return route.url.join('/') === 'gwt';
  }

  public store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: DetachedRouteHandle): void {
    this.cache[route.url.join('/')] = handle;
  }

  public shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return this.cache[route.url.join('/')] != null;
  }

  public retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle {
    return this.cache[route.url.join('/')];
  }

  public shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return future.url.join('/') === 'gwt';
  }
}
```

You need to provide the strategy in you application module providers so it will be used by the router.

```
@NgModule({
  …,
  providers: [
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: GwtRouteReuseStrategy}
  ],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Here is also a link to a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dzzhke-route-reuse?file=src%2Fapp%2Fgwt-route-reuse-strategy.ts) sample where you can see it working. Open the console to see that the 'GwtComponent' does not get destroyed when you navigate away.

Comment: In the GWT component, I put my GWT Application in an iFrame. Although by using the RoutingReuseStrategy, the ngOnDestroy was not being called, but on navigating back and forth through that page, the js and css files of the application was getting reloaded again and again. Can you suggest something on this?

Comment: I tried with an `iframe` an it is an issue as you say. I posted another answer with a workaround solution.